# Android menu options doesn't higlight on click/touch

Tags: android, click, highlight, menuitem

I am displaying menu action bar at the bottom of the screen. when user click/touch any of the menu item, i want to highlight it (i.e. the way button click highlighting happens). i tried  onClickListener and ontouchListener but it doesn't highlight.

can someone tell me which porperty/method i have set.

Here is code i am using.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.landing_page_layout);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.show();

// business logic }



    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_items, menu);

            item1 = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_option1);
            item1.getActionView().setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

 // logic when user touch menu option1 touch      
 }});
```

Thanks
Chintan

Comment: Could you post some code of what you are trying?

Comment: i shared code. please let me know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check this section in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu

To set the menu up you do this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Where R.menu.menu points to your res/menu/menu.xml file. This will load the elements from that file

The options menu is listened to in the same way as regular View's with OnClickListeners and such. Instead you `onOptionsItemSelected` override like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item1:
            // Do something
            return true;
        case R.id.item2:
            // Do something else
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```